# Autoscaling Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale

We have an application that uses Azure SQL for the database backend. Under normal load/conditions this database can successfully run on a Premium 1 plan. However, during the early morning hours we have jobs that run that increase database load. During these few hours we need to move to a Premium 3 plan. The cost of a Premium 3 is about 8 times more, so obviously we do not want to pay the costs of running on this plan 24/7.

Is it possible to autoscale the database up and down? Cloud services offer an easy way to scale the number of instances in the Azure Portal, however, nothing like this exists for Azure SQL databases. Can this be done programmatically with the Azure SDK? I have been unable to locate any documentation on this subject.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After digging through the articles in @ErikEJ's answer (Thanks!) I was able to find the following, which appears to be newly published with the release of the Elastic Scale preview:

[Changing Database Service Tiers and Performance Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn369872.aspx)

The following REST APIs are now newly available as well, which let you do pretty much whatever you want to your databases:

[REST API Operations for Azure SQL Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn505719.aspx)

And for my original question of scaling service tiers (ex. P1 -> P3 -> P1):

[Update Database REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn505718.aspx)

With these new developments I am going to assume it's only a matter of time before autoscaling is also available as a simple configuration in the Azure Portal, much like cloud services.

Comment: Too bad the service objectives aren't the simple "P1" style identifiers that humans know and understand. ;)

Comment: Yea, I don't really get that, but from my testing you must provide the Name, Edition, and ServiceObjectiveId (GUID) if you are scaling tiers.

Comment: @DavidPeden, do a `select * from slo_service_objectives` - that gives you the mapping between objective id and names like "P1" or "S2".

Comment: you can use t-sql version of alter database to do this. However note that auto scaling is not in place and it takes a few minutes to couple hours (size of the database) to scale up / scale down. Alter database <db> Modify (edition = 'Premium', service_objective = 'P1') should does the trick too

Comment: Just a FYI for everyone, here are all the current known service object ids: http://pastebin.com/SnNRFxrs

Comment: @SirishaChamarthi: Error: Can not alter the database, User must be in the master database. Where and how can u run that command?

Comment: You should connect to the master and execute this (in case of V12, this works from connecting the user db too).

Comment: It's 4 years after this answer was given and Autoscaling is still not an option.  Microsoft is really dropping the ball - I have not been impressed with their Azure products so far :-(

Answer (score 13):

Another way to do it is using Azure automation and using run book below:

```
param
(
    # Desired Azure SQL Database edition {Basic, Standard, Premium}
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
    [string] $Edition,

    # Desired performance level {Basic, S0, S1, S2, P1, P2, P3}
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
    [string] $PerfLevel

)

inlinescript
{
    # I only care about 1 DB so, I put it into variable asset and access from here
    $SqlServerName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'SqlServerName'
    $DatabaseName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'DatabaseName'


    Write-Output "Begin vertical scaling script..."

    # Establish credentials for Azure SQL Database server 
    $Servercredential = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("yourDBadmin", ("YourPassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force)) 

    # Create connection context for Azure SQL Database server
    $CTX = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ManageUrl “https://$SqlServerName.database.windows.net” -Credential $ServerCredential

    # Get Azure SQL Database context
    $Db = Get-AzureSqlDatabase $CTX –DatabaseName $DatabaseName

    # Specify the specific performance level for the target $DatabaseName
    $ServiceObjective = Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServiceObjective $CTX -ServiceObjectiveName "$Using:PerfLevel"

    # Set the new edition/performance level
    Set-AzureSqlDatabase $CTX –Database $Db –ServiceObjective $ServiceObjective –Edition $Using:Edition -Force

    # Output final status message
    Write-Output "Scaled the performance level of $DatabaseName to $Using:Edition - $Using:PerfLevel"
    Write-Output "Completed vertical scale"
}
```

Ref: 

[Azure Vertically Scale Runbook](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-SQL-Database-e957354f)

Setting schedule when u want to scale up/down.

For me, I used 2 schedules with input parameters, 1 for scaling up and another one for scaling down. 

 Hope that help.

Comment: Awesome! This solution involves some more reading (learning how to create an Automation Account, a new Asset (Credential), a new Runbook (this one) and a new Schedule. But it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: This is a great answer, and can be done through the *Classic Azure Portal*. (1) Create an automation account (2) Assets > Add > Credential > PS credential > {Your DB Admin creds} (3) Import the above runbook (follow link and download first) (4) To test: Author > Draft > Start, supply credential name from above and other params.  (5) If all good, publish runbook and create schedule (pretty self explanatory).

Comment: imported the above runbook in the gallery, works a treat.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, that feature has is available: Azure SQL Database Elastic Scale

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-scale-introduction

Comment: Elastic scale doesn't seem to do autoscaling, it's for partitioning/sharding data across multiple databases. For big scenario's this is helpful, not for scaling during the day

Comment: @ErikO - not sure why you think that: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-elasticity/

Comment: ErikO's link seems broken, try this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-introduction/

Answer (score 10):

In some cases the easiest option might be to just run SQL query as [described in msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt574871.aspx).

For example:

```
ALTER DATABASE [database_name] MODIFY (EDITION = 'standard', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S3', MAXSIZE = 250 GB)
```