# How can we autoscale the pricing tier of Azure SQL database?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, autoscaling, azure-elasticpool

As similar to app service plan, can we autoscale pricing tier of azure SQL database? Currently, my database is in standard S2 tier and I want scale out it's tier in S3 when CPU utilization reached up 80% and similarly want to scale in when it's down to 60% to S2.

I was going through many links and found this is old question/answer but wanted to check if we have any options available for the same.

[Autoscaling Azure SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782235/autoscaling-azure-sql-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single Azure SQL Database supports *manual* dynamic scalability, but not autoscale. For a more automatic experience, consider using elastic pools, which allow databases to share resources in a pool based on individual database needs. However, there are scripts that can help automate scalability for a single Azure SQL Database. For an example, see Use [PowerShell to monitor and scale a single SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-monitor-and-scale-database-powershell).

Comment: Thanks Ken... I'll look into the powershell script and will check how I can modify to use with existing database...